# Schedule SQL Server 2012 report to SFTP

Tags: sql-server-2012, scheduled-tasks, sftp

I have a requirement to auto upload a report nightly and transfer using SFTP. I can create the report in SQL Server 2012 but how can I auto save it to a specific folder in a flat file format (`.csv` / `.txt`)?

Once it is saved, it needs to be scheduled to upload and get transferred using SFTP. Could someone please advise and assist me with it? Thank you so much.

Update: Here is the extraction part. I created a .bat file that I have scheduled in windows task manager using SQLCMD. Now I can schedule it to auto-upload using the WinSCP commands. Just thought to update the answer for future users.

```
SQLCMD -S Servername -d databasename -U username -P password -i C:\sample.sql -o C:\sampletemp.txt -s"|" -W
findstr /B /V /C:"----" "C:\sampletemp.txt" > "C:\finaloutput.txt"
del "C:\sampletemp.txt"
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it.  I use WinSCP to transfer with SFTP, SSIS to do import/export and execute WinSCP, and SQL Agent to schedule it all.

Comment: We are also going to use WinSCP. Currently, I create and run the reports. However, we haven't used the SSIS or SQL Agent functionality. How can I find out if we have the ability to do so and do you have any good step by step tutorial on how I can accomplish this? May be something with the task scheduler??Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To setup SSIS SFTP task using WinSCP:

- In Visual Studio [create new *Integration Services Project* project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-1-creating-a-new-integration-services-project).
- In the project add a new *Execute Process* task.
- Point it to the `winscp.exe` executable with arguments to start an upload script.

  For details, see WinSCP guide to [SFTP Task for SSIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: We are thinking of using Windows Task Scheduler or Sql Server agent.

Comment: @sky_limit For task scheduler, see WinSCP guide to [scheduling file transfers to SFTP server](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it. We have Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server Standard or Enterprise, you have SSIS.  If you have SQL Server Web or better (i.e., not Express) then you have SQL Agent.

"How do I use SSIS?" is a question somewhat beyond the scope of a question on Stack Overflow.  It's a full ETL package.  Microsoft has some [basic SSIS tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx) you can go through but it is a very deep system.

That's how you're supposed to do it.  How MS intends people to do it.  You can also use the Import/Export Wizard, which lets you save an SSIS package at the end of the wizard for later use.  That won't help with scripting the WinSCP transfer, though.

If that feels like using a sledgehammer to drive a nail (or you're on SQL Express or Web) then the most basic way to do this would be to use a PowerShell script.  In 2008/2008 R2 there's the `SqlServerCmdletSnapin100` snap-in.  Beginning with 2012, that changed to the `SQLPS` module.  Note that snap-ins (`Get-PSSnapin -Registered`) are different than modules (`Get-Module -ListAvailable`) but they otherwise function very similarly; modules are just newer, AFAIK.  They both have `Invoke-Sqlcmd`.  You can also use .Net methods in System.Data.SqlClient if you're not installing SQL Server on the machine running the script, but that's a bit more involved.

So you can then do something like:

```
#Add the relevant snap-in/module; for 2012 that's sqlps
#Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100;
Import-Module sqlps;

#Fetch the data
$Query = 'SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM MyView ORDER BY Field1;';
$Data = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Server MyServer -Database MyDatabase;

#Save data to file
$Data | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Script\MyExportFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation;

#Run the WinSCP script to upload the data
#Note that --% is Powershell's "Stop parsing" operator; it keeps the parser from messing with the arguments.
&"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" --% -console -script="C:\Script\WinSCPScript.txt" -log="C:\Script\Logs\WinSCP-!S-!Y-!M-!D-!T.log" -xmlgroups
```

Then you just have to code your WinSCP script file, and schedule the script with Windows Task Scheduler.